# Anyone have a pointer for what is needed to make an MP3 Tag applicaiton?

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, tags

I get FLAC files a lot and want to automate the taging of the end point MP3 files after I have converted them.

What is my best library to interface with?  Vista machine and C# for my code base.

The flac files come with a text file for the show, and the numbers performed.  I'll edit that any way possible.

I use winamp for a player but will try others if free.  :)

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Check out libid3tag...  [http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=12349](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3"Wikipedia")...

And, actually, the ID3 tag is prettty simple, it's just text (with fixed length fields) tacked on to the front of the MP3 file...

Just make sure you follow the standard, as not all players, etc. do.  For more on that, check out this article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3"Wikipedia")

[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out TagLib# (google it).  It's not too hard to use, and makes reading and writing ID3 tags and other metadata pretty easy.

I've used it an ASP.NET project in the past, to automatically populate a database record using metadata from the ID3 tag of uploaded mp3 and mp4 files, with no major problems.